# gRaphael: How to increase spacing between bars in bar graph

Tags: raphael, graphael, bar-chart

I have created a horizontal bar graph using gRaphael charting library. I want to increase the spacing between the bars. Is there an option to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, from what I know there's not exactly a way to increase spacing but you can do so by manipulating the gutter value during initialization.

See:

[g.raphael docs here](https://github.com/qoelet/g.raphael/commit/a51f62631aa287b4718e676216e51cec65276579)

Answer (score 0):

increase the gutter. It can be received as an option or just change g.bar.js

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen using the dotchart, the spacing is controlled indirectly using the `width` and `height` of a chart.

I originally thought that the `x_coords` and `y_coords` variables I have below specify the exact pixel locations of the data, but it appears they only indirectly control this.

```
var r = Raphael(div_tag);  

r.dotchart(x_center,y_center,width,height,x_coords,y_coords,data, {symbol: "o", max: 10, heat: true, axis: "0 0 1 1", axisxstep: axisx_step, axisystep: axisy_step, axisxlabels: g_xaxis, axisxtype: " ", axisytype: " ", axisylabels: g_yaxis}
```

So the spacing is proportional to width/(# of values on the x axis) .